# create a .change() to replace .click() or something similar

Tags: javascript, html

Hi all so I am trying to redirect to another section of a form and cause a change effect. Currently I have a click effect which causes the thing I wanted to be clicked to click upon redirect.

```
function redirectToForm(selectedformID){
        document.getElementById("tab-three").checked = true; //checked the tab
        document.getElementById('selectList').value = selectedformID; //assigned selected value to be SelectedformID
        $('selectList').click(); //causes the click effect.
}


<select name="selectList"  id="selectList" onclick="getFormInfo(this.getSelected().getProperty('value'));">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Submitted Reports</option>
<option value="1">form 1</option>
...
...
</select>
```

This is my current setup and it works, however I want to change the `onclick="getFormInfo(this.getSelected().getProperty('value'));"` to be `onchange="getFormInfo(this.getSelected().getProperty('value'));"`

is there a way of still producing that `element.click();` effect? using `onchange=""` ?
I've been looking but I can't seem to produce the same or similar affect.

Comment: You do know you can have both, right?

Comment: I did  but I thought it would be considered bad practice, but that does work in my case since i am just pulling information, i'm not updating or anything

Comment: I would argue it's not bad practice, and actually is more straight forward than adding logic to make an on change also behave like an on click.

Comment: Well i'm not arguing with that I appreciate it @Taplar